# Getting data from thunk in node, mysql, koa

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql, koa, thunk

I want to get some data out of my MySQL database using Koa and the `mysql` node package. I was looking at [co-mysql](https://github.com/coderhaoxin/co-mysql), but the readme suggests to use `thunkify` directly. So I did the following:

```
const query = thunkify(connection.query.bind(connection));
```

Which seems to work, as I now can do:

```
app.use(function * main() {
  const races = yield query(
    "SELECT * FROM `races` where '2016-01-19' between start_date and end_date"
  )(function(err, rows) {
    // rows is the data I need
  });
});
```

However, I cannot find a way to return/yield the row data from the thunk into my races variable. I log it, and it displays the correct data, but when I try to pass it back, it always returns undefined. I've tried a couple of ways from inside the callback, but I can't seem to figure it out:

`return rows`
`yield rows` (made the callback a generator function)
`return yield rows`
...

I'm often getting: `TypeError: You may only yield a function, promise, generator, array, or object, but the following object was passed: "undefined"`

Comment: When using co with thunkify, I don't think you're supposed to define the callback yourself. Try `const races = yield query(...);`. It should return `rows` if successful and throw `err` if it fails.

Comment: @danneu Thanks for the reply. I've tried what you said and it returns an array containing 2 arrays, which apparently map to what the .query function should return (rows and fields) when used without co. So doing races[0] will get me the rows I need. I'll go with that for now, wondering if there's a better way though.

Comment: I recommend creating a db.js file that has generator functions like `getRaces` that execute the query and yield back the part of the data you want. That way, in your routes, you can just call `const race = yield db.getRaces();` without having to access the raw query response array every time. Also, you can write a helper function like `queryRows`, built on top of the query function, that accesses the part of the array you almost always want. DRYs up the code in your db.js module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`races` is an array because you are using `thunkify` for `query`. co returns an array for any thunks that call their callback with more than one value (ie. `callback(null, 1, 2, 3)` returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

If you were to Promisify `query` instead, `races` will be assigned to the first returned value only, which appears to be inline with what you're looking for.

Here's a code example showing it in practice:

```
var co = require("co")
var promisify = require("bluebird").promisify
var thunkify = require("thunkify")

function async(callback) {
    callback(null, 1, 2, 3)
}

var p = promisify(async)
var t = thunkify(async)

co(function*() {
    let x = yield p()
    let y = yield t()
    console.log(x)
    console.log(y)
}).then(() => {})
```

When run, the value of `x` will be `1` and the value of `y` will be the array `[1, 2, 3]`.

You can run it with Tonic here: https://tonicdev.com/56ab7cfc879afb0c002c1d49/56ab7cfc879afb0c002c1d4a